# jQuery Datatables Button CSS Positioning

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, datatable

I'm working on a Sharepoint web part that is utilizing JQuery datatables to format some reporting results, here's what the report looks like:

[image]

I'm having an issue with the 'Export to Excel' button.  This is the native button generated by datatables.  I have a class on the button as such:

```
.FSexportButton 
{
position: absolute;
right: -7px;
bottom: -20px;
}
```

and the class is associated when the table is initialized.  It looks fine (like the picture) as long as the report has data, but if not the positioning goes way off and the button moves.  The CSS from the jQuery is overriding the CSS in the class and making the position of the button 'relative'.  Basically I'm trying to figure out how to keep that button where it is in the picture regardless of the size of the div.

I added another class:

```
a.dt-button.advisorsExportButton {
position: absolute;
right: -7px;
bottom: -175px;
}
```

so now the button is positioned absolutely however, the div that was originally position: relative is being overwritten.

Comment: Initialize the data table only if you have any record

Answer (score 3):

The wrong way:

```
.FSexportButton 
{
position: absolute !important;
right: -7px;
bottom: -20px;
}
```

the right way: give it an id, lets say: 'excelbutton' and do

```
#excelbutton
{
position: absolute;
}
```

, or figure out the class that gives it relative and do .relativecclass.FSexportbutton like:

```
.relativeclass.FSexportbutton
{
position: absolute;
}
```

In css the more specific rules always override the previous ones

Comment: Aschab, thanks for the comment.  So if I go with #excelButton, do I still refer to the class the same way?  className: 'excelbutton'

Comment: what I propose its to give it the ID excelbutton, ID and CLASS are 2 different things. class is generic and id is specific you reference classes like: .class and ids like: #ids maybe this will help you: https://css-tricks.com/the-difference-between-id-and-class/

Comment: Since the button is generated by the JQuery plugin, I'm not really sure how to give that an ID.  So pulling up the Chrome tools, I see three classes associated with the styles for the button.  How do I figure out which one is setting position:relative?

Comment: with a chrome explorer right click and hit 'console', check the html it have to be <a> or <button> select it and see at your right all css asociated with it, look for a position: relative. For example on this page the 'add comment' button have on the css position relative with this: input[type="submit"], so to override it we need: input[type="submit"].FSexportButton

Comment: So position: relative is under this - button.dt-button, div.dt-button, a.dt-button.  How do I determine which class is actually the one setting it.

Comment: the button its a <button> a <div> or an <a>?